# what is the meaning of "Make a dragon wanna retire man"

Tags: phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of "Make a dragon wanna retire man" from "uptown funk" song in below:

> I’m too hot (hot damn)
>   Make a dragon wanna retire man

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is lyric interpretation.

Comment: @KristinaLopez - it is a very literal unambiguous interpretation, though.

Comment: @Josh61: I'd have closevoted as Too Localised if we still had that available as a reason, but I'll go along with Kristina here. For much the same reason, really - non-obvious things in song lyrics, poetry, etc. are usually effectively "one-offs" (and/or a matter of opinion - i.e. POB). And if we really accept your "literal unambiguous interpretation" position, I'd have thought that makes it also Too Basic.

Comment: the ", man" part on the end is, simply, the "man" you can throw on the end of ANY setnece.  (Same as "dude".)  "Nice car, man"  "Great house, man"

Comment: non-obvious???  it couldn't be more obvious.  dragons are "hot" and "fiery".  there is utterly no connection to **lyric interpretation** here, in the sense of what was the psychology of this blah blah...

Comment: Note that the fourwords before the mention of dragon are "too hot hot damn".  Perhaps this gives a clue?

Comment: it can't easily be obvious for those  who aren't native.

Comment: Please explain what you don't understand about the phrase, showing the research you have done. If you are still learning the language, you might like the site for [ell.se]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am so hot (slang for attractive) that a dragon (who breathes fire) will want to to retire, since they realise they can't possibly compete with me and be 'hotter' than me.

To be clear the ", man" on the end can be added on any sentence ("Nice shoes, man").

Comment: Yes, of course, perfectly explained.